# Romanian Hex Escape Codes?

Tags: c, hex, translation, ansi-escape, unicode-escapes

I am translating stuff from an application to Romanian (already did German), and I need hex escape codes for ă â ș ț î.

Like the German "ü" is \x81, are there hex escape codes for those Romanian characters?

I couldn't find any after 30 minutes of research.

Comment: Those code-page dependent characters are old style. Try to use the [unicode characters](https://www.fileformat.info/info/charset/UTF-8/list.htm).

Comment: The values depend on the encoding you use. Which encoding do you use?

Comment: 30 minutes of research on such a complex topic sounds not enough. ;-) You could at least write a simple experimental program to try _all possible values_ to see if any of them renders characters you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're probably best off using unicode escapes

`\u00fc` for "ü"

`\u0103` for "ă"

`\u00e2` for "â"

`\u00ee` for "î"

`\u0163` for "ţ"

Answer (score 0):

[Code page 850](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_850)  has "ü" as \x81.  That code page does not support `ă ș ț î`.

Instead use a more modern and comprehensive encoding like [Unicode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode).  See also [Romanian_alphabet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Romanian_alphabet#Unicode_and_HTML).

ISO/IEC 8859 might work for OP, yet that is not the best way going forward.